# How to resend messages from X-DEAD-LETTERS queue to another?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

Here are my two RabbitMQ queues and the method:

```
private final Queue igListenerQueue;
private final Queue igDlxQueue;

@WriteOperation
public void sendDeadMessages(String serviceName, Integer messageCount) {
    //igListenerQueue.addArgument("messages", igDlxQueue.getArguments());
}
```

I need to take n=messageCount messages from DlxQueue and to relocate them to igListenerQueue.
Here are my queues beans:

```
@Bean(IG_LISTENER)
@Profile("!qa")
public Queue igListenerQueue() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", rabbitIgDlxProperties.getExchangeName());
    args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", rabbitIgDlxProperties.getRoutingKey());
    return new Queue(rabbitIgListenerProperties.getQueueName(), true, false, false, args);
}

@Bean
@Profile("!qa")
public Queue igDlxQueue() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", rabbitListenerProperties.getExchangeName());
    return new Queue(rabbitIgDlxProperties.getQueueName(), true, false, false, args);
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `@RabbitListener` method to consume from the queue and send them to the other queue using a `RabbitTemplate`.

There's an example in the [Spring Cloud Stream documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-dlq-processing).